# how to prove that the Jordan curve is really the boundary of its regions

Tags: general-topology

Assume that we have proved that a Jordan curve $C$ disconnects the plane into two parts $int(C)$ and $ext(C)$. How can we argue that the boundary of $int(C)$ (resp. $ext(C)$) is exactly $C$ but not just part of $C$?

Comment: union of the two parts is the complement of the curve C?